# How to say "The following" in Japanese

Tags: grammar, translation

Since the word order in Japanese is kinda vague and also mostly reversed to what English speakers are used to, I always wondered how to say things like that in Japaense:

1. `The boy said the following: 'Sample Text'`
2. `Please look at the following picture.`

I also do not know what "the following" in general means in Japanese. https://jisho.org/search/the%20following
I never heard any of those that Jisho.org have listed.

Comment: I don't quite get the question. The answer is already in the link you gave. 以下 and 下記 are used a LOT and they mean "the following" or the alternative "below"

Comment: Can you help me understand the usage by putting those word into an example sentence please?

Comment: @UpdateDotExe maybe you meant specifically spoken language? It may not be so black & white, but 以下 suggests "below", which in text is OK as the "following" text (typically) appears below. But when speaking, as the next sentence comes rather "after" than "below", one often uses 次 . A sentence similar to your 1. is often heard in e.g. TV news, in the form where the news casters in the studio have told that they asked Mr. X to give a comment on something, and before switching over to the video clip of Mr. X, they say "Xさんは次のように述(の)べました". Even in speech, I think that 以下のように it not totally wrong.